# Show sub-menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask you for help. I'm trying to show submenu on click.

page: [www.marekmelena.eu][1]

On left side you can see few menus. They are created automatically by wordpress. 
I would like to have "sub2, sub3" hidden as default. But after click "#main" they should be visible.

I tried few solutions from this website already, but somehow it does not work.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 there should be script, right?
</script>
</head>
```

I'm calling menu by:

```
 <div class="menu-style">
   <h4><?php $nav_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object(6); echo $nav_menu->name; ?></h4>
   <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
 </div>
```

And this is result (**i want to hide/show class submenu**):

```
<h4>Hlavní menu</h4>

<div class="menu-hlavni-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-hlavni-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-61">
       <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/transparentni-ucet/">#main</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74">
        <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub2/">sub2</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73">
           <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub3/">sub3</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76">
      <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub2/">sub2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75">
              <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub3/">sub3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-82">
     <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/transparentni-ucet/">Transparentní účet</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-83">
         <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/o-hw-world-kontakt/">O HW World, kontakt</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://marekmelena.eu/clankyblog/">Články/blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thank you for help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toggle()` to show or hide the `.sub-menu` element.

- [.toggle() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

or `.slideToggle()` to show or hide the `.sub-menu` element with a sliding motion for some extra "*oohlala*" (© [Matthew Corway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1911434/matthew-corway))

- [.slidetoggle() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Don't forget to `.preventDefault()` to cancel the redirect event (click on a `<a>` with href).

[.preventDefault() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu-item > a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Hlavní menu</h4>

<div class="menu-hlavni-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-hlavni-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-61">
       <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/transparentni-ucet/">#main</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74">
        <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub2/">sub2</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73">
           <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub3/">sub3</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76">
      <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub2/">sub2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75">
              <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/sub3/">sub3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-82">
     <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/transparentni-ucet/">Transparentní účet</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-83">
         <a href="http://marekmelena.eu/o-hw-world-kontakt/">O HW World, kontakt</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://marekmelena.eu/clankyblog/">Články/blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or use [SlideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) for some extra oohlala (professional term).

Comment: thank you! I had to put <script></script> at the end of file. So it shows it properly.

Howeever, links does not work. Any clue? You can see that on that page.

thank you very much!

Comment: If you keep your link active, you will leave the page. Try it in removing `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: To resolve this, you could set the anchors that are only there to expand or collapse the sub-menus to `href="#"`.

Comment: I see. It allowed links, but it is instantly load page to clicked link... Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Chris Yongchu And the SEO ?

Comment: For that, you could add `rel="nofollow"` (i.e., <a href="#" rel="nofollow">)

Comment: > "Nofollow" provides a way for webmasters to tell search engines "Don't follow this specific link.". I told exactly the opposite. Keep your URLs in your `href` for [internal links](https://moz.com/learn/seo/internal-link) or [external links](https://moz.com/learn/seo/external-link), it's just SEO best practices.

Comment: @tmaven What do you really want ? Go to the external link or open current `.sub-menu` ? If you open the link with `taget="_blank"`, your current page will loose the focus. So, I don't see a good workaround.

Comment: @Robiseb Is it possible that submenu will stay visible after click on it? For example: http://marekmelena.eu ; test is first level, but when I click 2nd level (Transparentni ucet) it will hide).

Comment: @tmaven By "will stay visible **after click on it**", you mean after page reload ? In that website when you click on the last link, you are relocated in an other page. So, the menu has its initial state (all submenus closed).

Comment: @Robiseb yes, after reload. Can I call any other script (for example in page.php) which will toggle that sub-menu visible?

I want to keep active submenu visible

Comment: @Robiseb I guess I fixed it! I added style into page.php

<?php get_header(); ?>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu {
 display:block;
}
</style>

<div class="content">
....

Comment: @tmaven You did it right. But you can put this line directly in your CSS file and just add the `.current-menu-ancestor` class on the right `a` with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Start by hiding your sub-menu`

```css
.sub-menu{
  display:none;
  }
```

then add some jQuery to show it when user clicks on "#main".
If you want the user to be able to hide it when they click again, use the toggle method, otherwise you can use the show method.

I made a simple codepen example:
http://codepen.io/ciammarino/pen/VmZrra

Good luck`